# Rotating Text to match the slope of a line

Tags: java, graphics, rotation

I cannibalized an existing example to illustrate the question. 
Basically a line is being drawn. 
The `X,Y` values for drawing the line are used to calculate the slope. 
That value is then used with a text value. 
The ultimate goal is to have the text `"ABC"` match the slope of the line.

Whenever the `X,Y` values (`pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y`) for the line change, the slope of the line should be calculated so the text changes to match the slope.

This sample shows that the text is rotating too much. The general slope calculation is used : `((pt2y - pt1y) / (pt2x - pt1x))`.

I am wondering if converting from slope to rotation is not the same.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BevelArrows
{
    public static void main ( String...args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable () {
            BevelArrows arrows = new BevelArrows();

            @Override
            public void run () {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Test" );

                frame.add ( new JPanel() {
                    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g ) {
                        arrows.draw ( ( Graphics2D ) g, getWidth(), getHeight() );
                    }
                }
                , BorderLayout.CENTER );

                frame.setSize ( 800, 400 );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setVisible ( true );
            }
        } );
    }

    void draw ( Graphics2D g, int width, int height )
    {
        g.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        g.setColor ( Color.WHITE );
        g.fillRect ( 0, 0, width, height );

            g.setColor ( Color.BLUE );
            int pt1x = 150;
            int pt1y = 10;
            int pt2x = 200;
            int pt2y = 200;
            g.drawLine (pt1x, pt1y, pt2x, pt2y);

            g.setStroke ( new BasicStroke ( 20.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL ) );

            Font font = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 10); 
            AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
            affineTransform.rotate((float)((pt2y - pt1y) / (pt2x - pt1x)),  0, 0);
            Font rotatedFont = font.deriveFont(affineTransform);
            g.setFont(rotatedFont);
            g.drawString("abc", 250, 25);
            g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After further research it isn't really the slope of the line that I need.

Instead of using :

```
 affineTransform.rotate((float)((pt2y - pt1y) / (pt2x - pt1x)),  0, 0);
```

I should use Math.atan2 :

```
 affineTransform.rotate( Math.atan2((pt2y - pt1y), (pt2x - pt1x)),  0, 0);
```

This is producing the results I need.